# Trouble exec'ing known installed executable

Tags: linux, command-line, pyqt, qml

I have recently installed PyQt4 and PyQt5 on my Arch system, but when I run "qmlviewer" in my terminal, it returns:

```
qmlviewer: could not exec '/usr/lib/qt/bin/qmlviewer': No such file.
```

I know I have qmlviewer -- a `locate` returns several directories where I have qmlviewer. It's just not in the directory that my terminal is exec'ing. How can I get my terminal to try and exec qmlviewer from a directory that it's actually in?

Comment: Is it possible that qmlviewer was in that directory before the recent installs?  If so, `bash` may have saved that location in its cache.  To clear the cache so that it will search the PATH next time, run `hash -r`.  See `man bash` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` keeps track of where commands are located.  (Otherwise it would have to search the PATH *everytime*.)  When executables are moved around, as may happen during an upgrade, the shell will be unaware that its path information is out of date.  The solution is to run `hash -r` which purges the shell's memory of path locations.  The next time that you try to run the executable, `bash` will search the PATH from scratch to find it.

A little demonstration will this in action.  Let's create a new command called `cmd1`:

```
# cp /bin/date /bin/cmd1
# cmd1
Tue Mar 18 22:27:23 PDT 2014
```

`bash` had to search the PATH to find `cmd1` but, once it has done that, it remembers, as the `type` command shows:

```
# type cmd1
cmd1 is hashed (/bin/cmd1)
```

Now, let's trick `bash` by moving our command:

```
# mv /bin/cmd1 /usr/bin/cmd1
# cmd1
bash: /bin/cmd1: No such file or directory
```

Here is the solution:

```
# hash -r
# cmd1
Tue Mar 18 22:28:20 PDT 2014
# type cmd1
cmd1 is hashed (/usr/bin/cmd1)
```

The relevant part of `man bash` is:

> ```
>  hash -rv command ...
>         The shell maintains a hash table which remembers the loca‐
>         tions of commands.  With no arguments whatsoever, the hash
>         command prints out the contents of this table.  Entries
>         which have not been looked at since the last cd command
>         are marked with an asterisk; it is possible for these
>         entries to be invalid.
>
>         With arguments, the hash command removes the specified
>         commands from the hash table (unless they are functions)
>         and then locates them.  With the -v option, hash prints
>         the locations of the commands as it finds them.  The -r
>         option causes the hash command to delete all the entries
>         in the hash table except for functions.
> ```

A slightly less-featureful version of the `hash` function is  included in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/hash.html).