# How does the builtin shell command "type" know the path of given commands?

Tags: linux, shell

How does the built-in shell command `type` know the path of a given command. Does the shell have a table for most used commands that includes the paths of those commands, or does the shell search those commands in the system?

Comment: good question, this posting explains it alot better than I can.  https://medium.com/@jalendport/what-exactly-is-your-shell-path-2f076f02deb4

Comment: Bash does keep a table.  It's called a "hash."  For details on how it works and when it goes wrong, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466032/trouble-execing-known-installed-executable/22497397#22497397)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most shells work the following way trying to find the program you entered:

1. Check whether the program is actually a defined function or alias
2. Check whether the program is actually a shell built-in
3. Iterate over the directories in the `$PATH` environment variable, separated by `:`
4. Fail if nothing could be found

Use the following command to display a list of directories that is used for matching:

```
echo "$PATH" | sed 's/:/\n/g'
```

Most shells also hash already found programs' paths, which can lead to problems if a program is moved around after a hashed match. See [John1024's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466032/trouble-execing-known-installed-executable/22497397#22497397) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The bash shell keeps a hash table of programs that have already been found in the path. The `type` built-in checks the name to see if it is an alias, a shell reserved word, a function, a built-in, or a disk file. If it is none of those, then it checks the hash table:

```c
/* If the user isn't doing "-a", then we might care about
   whether the file is present in our hash table. */
if (all == 0 || (dflags & CDESC_FORCE_PATH))
    {
        if (full_path = phash_search (command))
            {
                if (dflags & CDESC_TYPE)
                    puts ("file");
                else if (dflags & CDESC_SHORTDESC)
                    printf (_("%s is hashed (%s)\n"), command, full_path);
                else if (dflags & (CDESC_REUSABLE|CDESC_PATH_ONLY))
                    printf ("%s\n", full_path);

                free (full_path);
                return (1);
            }
    }
```

It searches the path if it can't find the name any other way:

```c
/* Now search through $PATH. */
while (1)
```

You can force the shell to forget the hash table by using something like

```
$ hash -r
```

Recommended reading: [bash source code for the type built-in](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/type.def)

Comment: Whether or not any particular shell maintains a hash table is an implementation detail of that particular shell. You should at least note which shell's source code you are quoting.

Comment: (POSIX specifies that the `hash` command [be defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/hash.html), but seems pretty vague about what it actually has to do. This comment: "The hash utility may be implemented as an alias-for example, alias -t -, in which case utilities found through normal command search are not listed by the hash command." suggests it doesn't really have to do anything.)

Comment: @chepner: You should edit my answer or create your own.